# Two jQuery scripts needs the same external JSON data - avoid duplicate downloads

Tags: jquery, performance

I have two jQuery scripts on one page. Both do different things independently, but use the same JSON data loaded from the same url with `$.getJSON()`. The data is fairly large so I want to avoid downloading it twice.

The thing is that there is no guarantee that bots scripts will be included on the page at the time. Usually both are needed but sometimes only one of them is needed.

How should I code the `$.getJSON()` logic to make sure that the data won't be downloaded twice, but at the same time both scripts will be capable to download the data independently in case only one script is included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method returns an object that implements the [`Promise`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) interface. Example pseudo code...

Main script:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

(function () {
    // create a local variable to hold the promise
    var promise = null;

    this.getData = function () {
        if ( promise === null ) {
            // make the call and store the promise only
            // if it hasn't already been created yet
            promise = $.getJSON(...).promise();
        }

        return promise;
    };
}).apply( MyApp );
```

Then in your two scripts (and any others that may need the same data) you can do:

```
$.when( MyApp.getData() ).done( function ( data ) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Some benefits:

- Only one call to `getJSON`
- It doesn't matter when other scripts call `getData` (or how often). Even if the promise has already resolved, they will always be able to access the data returned from the server in a [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) handler.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I only had to replace `$.getJSON` with `jQuery.getJSON` for use in druapl. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data $.getJSON gets and check for that variable before the $.getJSON calls.

`if (typeof jsondata === 'undefined') {
     $.getJSON('url', function(data){
        var jsondata=data;
    }
}
//use the jsondata variable`

Comment: OK, but if first script starts to load the data and second script needs the data? At this point the `jsondata` is `undefined` and the code will fail. I need some kind of semaphore but I'm not sure what are the best practices for `jQuery`.